# What does FMTONLY in SQL Server stands for?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've recently worked with FMTOnly to hide metadata information being passed in a store procedure, however i can't find any information about what "FMT" means.
What does "FMT" mean?

Source:
[SET FMTONLY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: It's just `FoRmaT`. But do you know you shouldn't be using this any more?

Comment: @DavidG yes, i'ts being used in an SP im maintaining so i just got curious about the naming to fully understand it.

Comment: This is used to return the *naked* resultset only (structure without rows). I have some dark memory that this can help to use Stored Procedures, which return more than one resultset, in Typed DataSets (C#) or in EntityFramework. Otherwise the prediction of the result was not clear / possible. But - as said - just dark memory...

Comment: From the documentation you cited: "Returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the **format** of the response without actually running the query." _[emphasis added]_

Comment: In Entity Framework it can be used to create an entity type